# Beta testing for in-App Purchase in Android

Tags: android, in-app-purchase, google-play, in-app-billing

I need to test my in-app Purchase app before uploading it in Google Play store.

I have created the Beta testing Group with my mail account. But still I am getting error "*App not available for this account*".

Please share your ideas for this.

Comment: after send request you got any email??? to download app from play store???

Comment: yes. And that link shows the above error "App not available for this account"

Comment: whatever devices you are using, you are log-in as same account in which you got email?? one more question when you have uploaded app on Google play(before 24 hours)??

Comment: yes.. I have used the same mail account and it's already passed 48hrs

Comment: An Alpha/Beta app must be published before the opt-in link will become active. Please note that it may take several hours for system to detect the app and activate the link. more detail https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/troubleshooter/3055329?hl=en#ts=3280770,3281354 and read full details from here https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/3131213?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

It may shown because you have not added account in **Gmail accounts with testing access**. You can add following way,

1. Open developer account for publishing app.
2. Go to **Setting**, you can find left hand side under **All Applications**
3. Scroll down in Setting, You can find **LICENCE TESTING** and add your accounts for you want to do testing.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: I have done these all. Still having the same error in  "App not available for this account" :(

Comment: Are you not able to download or purchase?

Comment: Please check you SKU Id entered in Play store must exactly same as entered in coding.

Answer (score 1):

According to the details of your question, You should check the following conditions.

1.The gmail account with which you want to test the application should join the beta testing group that you have created.

2.The device from which the application will be tested has to be logged in with the test account - the one that has joined your beta testing group.

3.The apk that you have uploaded to the developer console must be published.

4.Note that it may take 3 to 4 hours after you publish your app to get recognized by google.